# JPA / How to fetch entity in read-only mode?

Tags: java, jpa

I am facing an issue, where I need to retrieve an entity two times in read-only mode to compare them ( need to have to seperate object's from db pointing the same entity, and before comparing I make some operations on them ).
Since my JPA and Hibernate are not supporting detach() in EntityManager, and I am not able to change it to a newer version, is there any workaround for that so I would be able to fetch those two ?

Thank you in advance for your help,

P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to achieve my goal by a workaround, using one of the features of Apache Commons library, and more precisely Common BeanUtils ( http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/ ).
It contains a way to copy the content of entity bean, which is detached, and further process without affecting the data in database.

Thank you for all help,

Regards,
P.

Answer (score 0):

You might transfer your entity into another bean like `MyUnmanagedEntity` after fetching. Simply use a subclass that is not mapped as `@Entity` and therefor won't be persisted. Init it using a proper constructor that takes the original and transfers all the fields you'll need.

Another way is to `close()` your `EntityManager` so it stops managing your entities. But this would affect all other managed entities as well.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for the hint. So as I understand is in someway a clone() on the entity, right ?

Comment: Yes, this is one possibility you might go for. If you use a subclass you only need to clone the fields of the class and not the code. But it hardly depends on the operations you want to make if you need to clone more than these simple entities. Don't forget references to other managed entities.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can obtain underlying Hibernate `Session` with `em.getDelegate()`, and call `evict()` on it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible using Hibernate specific features, but for me, unfortunately I need to stick to the JPA specification.